# How can I pass back the purchase receipt to the JavaScript using Cordova WP8?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using [this](https://github.com/kavukattu/phonegap-iap-wp8) cordova plugin

How can I pass back the purchase receipt to the JavaScript.

I tried with this:

```
string receiptXml =  await CurrentApp.GetProductReceiptAsync(productListing.ProductId);
string res = String.Format("\"receipt\":\"{0}\"",receiptXml);
res = "{" + res + "}";
this.DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, res));
```

But the receipt is not returned to the JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Fovea's purchase plugin has WP8 and receipt validation support: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

(and it also supports iOS and Android).